# La oración "Se mostraba indiferente a lo que pudiera pensarse de él" ¿es relativa o completiva?

Tags: sintaxis

> Se mostraba indiferente *a lo que pudiera pensarse de él*.

Ya había puesto algunas veces preguntas de este tipo pero lamentablemente aún no estoy segura. Tiendo a pensar que esto es una oración relativa (con el pronombre *lo* que se refiere a su actitud (*mostrarse indiferente*) pero como ya he dicho no estoy segura...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ésta parece ser una subordinada completiva, ya que no se la puede suprimir sin cambiar el sentido.

Es una estructura que no es tan fácil de encontrar en las gramáticas porque en vez de un verbo que tiene por sujeto, objeto o complemento una subordinada, la subordinada depende de un adjetivo:

> *Se mostraba indiferente a lo que pudiera pensarse de él.*
> = *No le importaba lo que pudiera pensarse de él.*
> = *Lo que pudiera pensarse de él le resultaba indiferente.*
>
> *Se mostraba indiferente a* [objeto de preposición]*.*
> = *No le importaba* [sujeto]*.*
> = [sujeto] *le resultaba indiferente.*

La palabra *lo* es aquí un artículo neutro (¡no un pronombre!) y precede obligatoriamente al pronombre relativo *que* (véase la parte inicial del artículo sobre *[que](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2VAvJgr6tD6bMa8swW)* en el DPD). El referente de este pronombre relativo compuesto, *lo que*, queda implícito. Se usa el género neutro porque el referente es abstracto, aunque si quisiéramos forzarlo a ser explícito, *«lo que podría pensarse...»* equivaldría a *«las cosas que podrían pensarse...»* o algo similar.

Comment: Muchas gracias! genial!!!